# Get list of Webhooks from Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I have built a Wordpress plugin that among other things, creates several Woocommerce Webhooks upon activation. This is done using internal API classes and functions, as per below:

```
function createWebhook($userID,$topic,$secret,$deliveryURL,$status)
{
    $webhook = new WC_Webhook();
    $webhook->set_user_id($userID); // User ID used while generating the webhook payload.
    $webhook->set_topic( $topic ); // Event used to trigger a webhook.
    $webhook->set_secret( $secret ); // Secret to validate webhook when received.
    $webhook->set_delivery_url( $deliveryURL ); // URL where webhook should be sent.
    $webhook->set_status( $status ); // Webhook status.
    $save = $webhook->save();
    return $save;
}
```

This works well.

What I want to be able to do is remove these Webhooks upon deactivation of the plugin. Is there any way to fetch the Woocommerce Webhooks via the internal Wordpress or Woocommerce API, so I can loop through and remove the relevant ones?

I would just remove all Webhooks where the delivery URL has a domain of xyz.com. This part is straight-forward, I just don't know how to fetch the Webhooks.

I don't want to use the external Woocommerce API, which requires an API key and HTTP requests.

Thanks

Comment: so - to run a function when deactivating your plugin, you use something like `register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivate' );`

Comment: And I guess, that you could just update the status to `'status'           => 'disabled',` ?

Comment: or just run `$webhook->delete()`

Comment: @Stender That I understand. How do I load the Webhook to be able to then disable or delete it though?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up querying the database to get the webhooks, which looks to be working well. I'm not sure there's any other way. Please let me know if there is!

```
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT webhook_id, delivery_url FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_webhooks" );
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        if(strpos($result->delivery_url, 'domain.com') !== false)
        {
            $wh = new WC_Webhook();
            $wh->set_id($result->webhook_id);
            $wh->delete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@greg's answer points you in the right direction, but the returned data is just an array of ID's for each webhook, to get more data you need to parse those ID's into webhook objects - which has protected props, but public getter methods, like so:

```php
$data_store = \WC_Data_Store::load( 'webhook' );
$webhooks   = $data_store->search_webhooks([ 'status' => 'active', 'paginate' => true ] );
$_items     = array_map( 'wc_get_webhook', $webhooks->webhooks );

$_array     = [];

foreach( $_items as $_item ){

    $_array[] = [
        'id'            => $_item->get_id(),
        'name'          => $_item->get_name(),
        'topic'         => $_item->get_topic(),
        'delivery_url'  => $_item->get_delivery_url(),
        'secret'        => $_item->get_secret(),
    ];

}
```

Comment: Probably more future-proof than my own solution posted here, but also seems very inefficient. I assume each wc_get_webhook call requires a separate query back to the database, in addition to the database query for search_webhooks().

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all webhook IDs with the following:

```
$data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'webhook' );
$webhooks   = $data_store->search_webhooks();
```

That's what WooCommerce does when building the table list:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-webhooks-table-list.php