# Create a webhook programmatically in wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, erp

i'm making a Plugin to make a integration of one ERP to Woocommerce and i'm thinking about using the web hooks for that integration, the problem create the web hooks when the plugin is activated for the first time, and not oblige people to create the woocommerce webhooks manually and configure them. i googled and tried several things but looks like no one works, also tried make a sql query, but don't worked.

i tried this:

```
function createWebhook($userID,$topic,$secret,$deliveryURL,$status)
{
    $webhook = new WC_Webhook();
    $webhook->set_user_id($userID); // User ID used while generating the webhook payload.
    $webhook->set_topic( $topic ); // Event used to trigger a webhook.
    $webhook->set_secret( $secret ); // Secret to validate webhook when received.
    $webhook->set_delivery_url( $deliveryURL ); // URL where webhook should be sent.
    $webhook->set_status( $status ); // Webhook status.
    $save = $webhook->save();
    return $save;
}
```

from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642092/get-list-of-webhooks-from-woocommerce)

without sucess, getting a lot of errors.

Anyway, thanks for the help. and i hope you'r ale in safety and with good health!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the webhook name

Add `$webhook->set_name('Webhook Name');`